# Usage of app.config in Host app and app.config in WCF library?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

Firstly I'm fairly new to WCF. I've done some projects but they are either hosted in IIS (so just the WCF library is involved without any host app) or the WCF class is declared right inside the host app project (so there is just 1 `app.config`).

Now I need to understand the code in a project (not of mine) in which the WCF library project is separate and it has its own `app.config` file, the host app project references that WCF library project and also has its own `app.config`.

I can see that those `app.config`s are different at least in the section for the `system.serviceModel`. The biggest difference is in one app.config (of host app) defines the services' endpoints using `netTcpBinding` while in the other app.config (of WCF lib), the `basicHttpBinding` is used. It's so confusing to me. So my question is when running the host app, which `app.config` is used, how does it determine to parse the `app.config` of its own and of the referenced WCF library? I doubt that the `app.config` of the WCF library project will be ignored but not so sure. Please give me something helpful involving this situation. Thank you!

Comment: app.config of a library is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WCF Library is no different than any other class library in .NET in terms of the config file.  A class library will use the config file of the application that is referencing it - the app.config file in the library project template is not used (and I'm not sure why it's even included, to be honest).

Generally, when you're developing a WCF class library, you will copy the relevant `<system.serviceModel>` section of the app.config to the config file (be it app or web) of the application that will host the service.

So to answer your question, the app.config file of the service library **will be** ignored, just as the config file of *any* library is.  The application hosting the service will take the service settings from it's config file.

Example:

Say you have a project named `MyServiceLibrary`.  You then create a console app named `MyServiceHost`, which references `MyServiceLibrary`.  The `MyServiceLibrary` project will use the `<system.serviceModel>` settings in the `MyServiceHost.exe.config` file (what the app.config file becomes when the project is compiled).  The app.config in the `MyServiceLibrary` project is ignored.

Comment: In fact I 80% think it should be ignored but with your answer I think I have 100%, thanks for the answer.